# returning a string from perl to bash

Tags: bash, perl

I'm Trying to return a string to my shell script and I get and error :
 `Can't return outside a subroutine at ...`

```
$result = "Error: $ARGV[0] changed!"
return ($result);
```

any ideas on how can i pass it back to my shell?

Comment: You would typically use `print "Error: $ARGV[0] changed\n"` or `say "..."`.
As the error message indicates, `return` is used to return values from a subroutine to its caller.

Comment: how can i catch the string in my shell script?

Comment: See the `$(...)` or `\`...\`` operators in your local `sh` man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash does not have the concept of a return value. Instead:

- Commands have an exit value which indicates success/failure. Exit code zero is success. Perl exits automatically with success if the script does not `die()`.
- Commands can write to a file descriptor, e.g. stdout. This output can be redirected and captured by Bash.

So if a program (written in Perl or otherwise) wishes to makes data available to Bash, it should print the data.

E.g. if we want to capture all output of a command on stdout:

```
result="$(yourcommand arg1 arg2)"
```

Often, the output is piped to a different command:

```
yourcommand arg1 arg2 | grep Error  # all lines including "Error"
```

Or written to a file:

```
yourcommand arg1 arg2 >file.txt
```